# Unspecified error in Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0 connection open to read excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledbconnection

I got a problem with Oledb12.0 connection open to read excel file in VB.NET. It works in local running. But there is unspecified error in running from Server. Connection string to read excel file is as following:

```
Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/")
If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath)
End If

filePath = String.Concat(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

Dim excelConnectionString As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", filePath)

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
     Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection)
     connection.Open()
```

I got the following message when I printout using a label in UI as I can't debug.

message + source + stackTrace

Unspecified errorMicrosoft Access Database Engine at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at massUpdateEmployeeParticular_pgForm.Upload() in D:\Data\Documents\My Projects\trunk\folder\folder\moduleName\pgForm.aspx.vb:line 140
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by an `Unspecified error`, could you givem more details?

Comment: I can't mention error details. Because I run the web application through IP, not local. So printout the error message in label as I can't debug.
Error what i get is 'An exception occurred: Unspecified error '. Thanks @Knorriemans for helping me

Comment: without any further info, it s basically impossible to help you. Do you have adequate rights to access the file on/from the server?

Comment: try putting ticks around the Extended props:  `"...Extended Properties='Excel 8.0'"`

Comment: thanks Konrriemans and @Plutonix
I already updated my questions as much as i can to solve my problem

Comment: your edit is still missing the ticks.  Since there is a space in "Excel 8.0", I think you need to enclose it as I showed.  I just wrote an OleDB-Excel parser thing and the connection string seemed to need ticks around the entire bit.

Comment: Current connection string works in localhost. But not in Server. I also tried as you said using ticks, and same error.